# Can I simulate a drop connection using fiddler?

Tags: proxy, fiddler, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to simulate a connection drop using fiddler apart from adding latency to slow down the requests for a long time.

Thanks,

Sid

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Fiddler's AutoResponder, change the action for a matching Session to `*drop` or `*reset`.

See http://youtu.be/3YZvZnTQhpo?t=4m26s

Comment: Thanks Eric! I wonder if there's a way to do the same via FiddlerScript ?

Comment: Never mind! I could find this info from your post here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/httpfiddler/Bf-DUuXbqfg